# Module parse failed - Webpack Angular/cli and xtermjs

Tags: angular, parsing, webpack, xtermjs

Currently I am using webpack config from angular cli and am facing the same issue of .map parser. Any work around for issue of parsing maps or addon loader? ES5 code works fine, its an issue with ES6 systemjs

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/xterm/lib/addons/search/search.js.map
Module parse failed: /home/jack/Projects/C290/website/node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js
```

Unable to hack into the webconfig. Removing .map files did not help

Update:

```
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent{
    xterm;
    constructor(){

      // Following line or not - it breaks with search.js.map
      //Terminal.loadAddon('search');

      // The following code when run breaks with the error
      this.xterm = new Terminal();
    }
}
```

This is the actual problem but where do cli webpack config changes apply?
https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js/issues/1018

https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js/issues/877

Comment: Do you have a minimalist example you can share?

Comment: Its a big app. Might not be able to put all the code. But I updated the actual code thats breaking.

Comment: which ts loader are you using?

Comment: I am unsure if I understand that? I am using cli 1.4.2. These are the sourcemap loaders. `"source-map-loader": "^0.2.0", "source-map-support": "^0.4.1"`

Comment: @pixelbits ok now I have the right loader. I am now using commonjs. A quick question - `Octal literal in strict mode (19:32) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` is occuring. The literal is `\033[1;3;31`. Whats the appropriate loader for these `\\` characters to be understood right? It works with normal text. Any idea of the needed loader?

Comment: When using webpack, you need a loader for every file type that it bundles. Which file is the error happening - HTML, image, css file, etc? `\033` looks like its the start of a binary file, like maybe an image

Comment: Yes its a canvas write with a string. What is happening is.. it is not allowing me to write strings with utf8  and character codes. I am looking at cli loaders and webpack builder/compiler packages and was unable to find where is the compiler config of cli resides that allows build to encompass the loaders as well during run time. The error happens during runtime of application after compile. Seems like it is expecting a loader for these characters during runtime which is unavailable in angular. What loader do you recommend and is the process of inclusion different from that of external chars?

Answer (score 0):

this issue should be fixed at xterm.js after the 3.0.0 release.

The following steps should help fixing your issue:

1. Get the latest release: https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/releases/tag/3.0.2
2. Replace `loadAddon` with the [new API for using addons](https://xtermjs.org/docs/guides/using-addons/) (manual import and `applyAddon`)

You can see a minimal example at how this works at https://github.com/parisk/xterm-webpack.

Comment: Yes got the 3x version already. Though some issues with resize does not seem to be fixed. Let me check again.